# Kendo UI bind datePicker to column

Tags: kendo-ui

So, I have kendo grid, in which i want date columns to be editable. It looks like this:

```
...
//and date field in options looks like this:
{
            field: "BirthDate",
            title: "Birth Date",
            format: "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",
            editor: dateEditor,
            editable: true,
            width: "120 px"
        }
```

How to bind datePicker via js function?
Is it something like

```
function dateEditor(container, options) {
           var input = $('<input name="' + options.field + '" required="required" />');
           input.appendTo(container)
           input.kendoDateTimePicker({});
 }
```

Comment: Yes, looks like you are in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question closed, editor added through dataSource schema (kendo autobinds datepicker to fields with "date" type).